# SQL Server: How can you turn a series of consecutive begin and end datetimes into a single begin-end range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have got a downtime list. It lists the beginning and end value of each downtime. I want to get the last date but every is date mingled.

Example:

We assume that every downtime are in the same day.

```
A)  begin 09:00 End 11:00
B)  begin 10:00 End 12:00
C)  begin 12:00 End 13:00
D)  begin 15:00 End 16:00
```

Test case :

```
1) 
At - 11:00  
Results: Begin A (9:00), End C (13:00)

2) 
At - 11:30  
Results: Begin B (10:00), End C (13:00)

3) 
At - 12:00  
Results: Begin B (10:00), End C (13:00)

4) 
At - 12:30  
Results: Begin C (10:00), End C (13:00)
```

If we only look at the "End" value. Its always the last date, every date mingled. its like putting every downtime in a single timeline. you put you and check when the downtime finish. Regardless of whether it is the downtime A or B or C ....

Note : only SQL query, no function. I prefer without recursive but.

---

From Mack Answer :

```
DECLARE @Downtime AS TABLE(beginDT datetime, endDT datetime)
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('09:00','11:00')
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('10:00','12:00')
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('12:00','13:00')
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('15:00','16:00')
```

I think I need a recursive. 
search @DateNow need to be between beginDT and endDT. and we need to check recursively if the endDT of each had another downtime.

In my sample, A-B-C are consecutive (or at the same time). so, if the currentTime is between the begging of A and the end of C, the real End time is the end of the tree downtime (13:00)

```
9    10   11   12     13     14      15     16

|----A----|

     |----B----|

               |---C---|

                                      |---D---|


|---- A and B and C ---|
```

Comment: Hi ForX,
You really need to include the table structures for us to be able to help properly.
Your current query would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so based on the extended data, you will (probably)need recursion:

--Test variables & environment

```
DECLARE @TimeParam AS DATETIME
DECLARE @Downtime AS TABLE(ID VARCHAR(1), beginDT datetime, endDT datetime)
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('a','09:00','11:00')
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('b','10:00','12:00')
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('c','12:00','13:00')
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('d','15:00','16:00')
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('e','12:00','17:00') 
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('f','15:00','19:00') 
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('g','19:00','20:00') 
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('h','20:00','21:00') 
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('i','21:00','22:00') 
INSERT INTO @Downtime VALUES('j','22:00','23:00')

SET @TimeParam ='1900-01-01 15:30:00.000'
```

--Query

```
DECLARE @Depth as INT --(Use this to control the recursion)
SET @Depth = 4
;WITH ConsecutiveDownTimeBase (ID, beginDT, endDT,IsBase)
AS 
(
SELECT ID
    , beginDT
    , endDT
    , 1 IsBase
FROM @DownTime dt
WHERE @TimeParam BETWEEN beginDT AND endDT
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT a.ID
    , a.beginDT
    , a.endDT
    , b.IsBase+1
FROM ConsecutiveDownTimeBase AS b
INNER JOIN @Downtime a
    ON b.endDT BETWEEN a.beginDT and a.endDT
    AND b.IsBase<=@Depth
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT c.ID
    , c.beginDT
    , c.endDT
    , b.IsBase+1
FROM ConsecutiveDownTimeBase AS b
INNER JOIN @Downtime c
    ON b.beginDT BETWEEN c.beginDT and c.endDT
    AND b.IsBase<=@Depth
)
SELECT CONVERT(TIME,MIN(beginDT)) AS beginDT
     , CONVERT(TIME,MAX(endDT))   AS endDT 
FROM ConsecutiveDownTimeBase
```

Here are the results:

```
beginDT             endDT
09:00:00.0000000    23:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: this only find time between, I want the last time . but your sample of table is great.

Comment: Can I ask whoever down-voted this answer to let me know why please?  I was flying blind when I answered it.

Comment: @forX I have edited the answer based on your revised question, hope this gives you what you need.  As well as the max end time range I have added min begin time just in case, if you don't need this just remove the dtBefore join and RangeStart column.

Comment: you assume the number of downtime. you cant. Add more downtime.
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('e','12:00','17:00')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('f','15:00','19:00')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('g','19:00','20:00')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('h','20:00','21:00')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('i','21:00','22:00')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('j','22:00','23:00')

Comment: Hey forX, have you reviewed the changes I made?  Did they help?

Comment: I did not. I look, at first, it look interesting, but the depth cause problem. It should not have a depth, I need the last time, regardless how many downtime. I add a few more and I got a wrong answer.